# How to open Activity via intent-filter and what is the use of intent-filter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm working with activities I know how to open activities via intent, but I want to know how can I open activity via intent-filter and what is the role of intent-filter to open activities.

- How many ways to open the activity?

Comment: where is your code? have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Intent intent=new Intent(this,QAActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); it is the simple way to open activity but i want to open via use of intent-filter

Comment: i have written code in manifest for intent-filter that is:-<activity
            android:name=".Activity.QAActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_user_profile" >
         <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="QAActivity" />
        </intent-filter>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity can even be launched via IntentFilter 
try this out

Basically when you install your app, Android system will register the activity with corresponding action, when you declare your activity with custom action, Android system stores the activity with the respective activity. When you launch the intent with your custom action. The system will find the receiving activity and launch it it there is only one activity matching it, if there are more than one Activity receiving that action, System will ask the user to choose which activity to complete the action.

declare `activity` in `manifest` as

```
       <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="your.custom.ACTION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

then you can start this activity by just calling

```
startActivity(new Intent("your.custom.ACTION"));
```

Answer (score 0):

An IntentFilter is used with BroadcastReceivers.
The BroadcastReceiver then gets activated when any intent that fits through the filter arrives in the system.

This is generally used to send messages between activities, between different applications, or from the server to the application.

See BroadcastReceiver documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

or this tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

Comment: can we use intent-filter to open own activity

Comment: Yes. In the onReceive() function of the BroadcastReceiver, create an Intent and use it to start your activity.